# add Javadoc for hibernate in netbeans

Tags: java, hibernate, netbeans

How to add javadoc in `netbeans`
mainly me using it for spring hibernate. Its not showing help and saying `Javadoc not found`
How to add doc for `org.​hibernate`
When selecting a function it is showing like this

```
    Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or
  you have not added specified Javadoc in the Java Platform Manager or the Library Manager.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to download the source and Javadocs for the Hibernate, the version you are using. You can easily find that by searching over the internet. After saving the docs and source on the disk some where appropriate,

Go to `project properties -> libraries -> select hibernate JAR -> click Edit -> browse to Javadocs and Source`.

Answer (score 3):

[Here is article along with pictorial representation how to add javadoc for any lib](http://nxadm.wordpress.com/2008/04/30/add-javadoc-of-a-third-party-library-to-netbeans-61/)

1. Go to sourceforge at http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/,
2. download the  3.2.2.ga hibernate bundle and include the javadocs and sources from there according to article describes [select version as per your lib].

Answer (score 1):

For my case I'm using **Netbeans 7.4** with **hibernate 3.6.10**. I was dealing with the same issue. Whene I do a <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> in order to get the documentation about Hibernate function, It's give me the following :

```
Javadoc not found. Either Javadoc documentation for this item does not exist or there is no attached Javadoc to the JAR file containing this item:E:\Programs\NetBeans 7.4\java\modules\ext\hibernate\hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final.jar
```

To solve it, I've downloaded the source [hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final-sources.jar.zip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl4eu.png) from : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/hibernate-core/hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final-sources.jar.zip and added it to my project libraries.

Finally I've got the documentation with <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> shoortcut :).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you download your Hibernate version it comes in a war bundle. Extract that .war file and you will see the folder of Hibernate. In it there is a folder named documentation.  Click on it and you will see the javadoc folder.

For configuring javadoc in NetBeans follow adeel ansari's answer.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to download the library from
[sourceforge hibernate3 zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hibernate/files/hibernate3/)

- Add The Jar from the library you downloaded **not** the one that comes with netbeans
- And Then In Project

> **Right click Project -->properties-->Libraries-->select Hibernate Jar-->Edit -->**

and browse the src folder and docs folder from dialog form the directory you have downloaded

[image 1](http://s13.postimage.org/dx1tq8aaf/library_netbeans.png)
[image 2](http://s14.postimage.org/72t6jyrqp/library_netbeans2.png)

Comment: i hope the image appear :)

Comment: i hope the image appear from image server  signed in

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same problem and a solution clicked to me.

1) Right click the project in the project window
2) go to the properties 
3) select the Libraries node.
4) select the library and press edit.
5)go to the javadoc tab and click add url.
6) Paste http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/ in the url window.

This is the link for the online Javadoc for Hibernate.

Comment: I followed your guide but it does not work for me. I restarted the ide rebuild the project etc... Nothing...

Comment: Which IDE you are using? With eclipse this works perfectly. Also please check your hibernate version. Here the version of hibernate is 4.2 so I put the URL for version 4.2.